# Consulta de duas tabelas VS + Access

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-access

Preciso interligar duas tabelas na mesma consulta, porém não tem dado muito certo. Eu criei este código:

```
try
    {
            String StringCon = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\02_Semestre\PI\00_Arquivos\01_Programação\tblContacts.mdb";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(StringCon);
            conn.Open();

            string query = "SELECT Campeonato.Nomecamp, Jogadores.Nome, Jogadores.Sobrenome AS Expr1, Rodadas.Nome AS Expr2 FROM((Rodadas INNER JOIN Campeonato ON Rodadas.Campeonato = Campeonato.Nomecamp) INNER JOIN Jogadores ON Rodadas.Nome = Jogadores.Nome AND Rodadas.Sobrenome = Jogadores.Sobrenome)";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", boxnome1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sobrenome", boxsobrenome1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campeonato", boxcam1.Text);

            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Jogador Cadastrado no sistema \n\n Bom Jogo!!!");
                btnInsert.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Jogador não cadastrado.");
            }
            }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(erro.Message);
        }
```

O problema é que não tem nenhum erro, mas não encontra o que preciso também. Acho que minha string está errada totalmente. Como fazer pra realizar essa busca após a digitação em 3 textbox?